# Talend to connect to the Marketing Cloud SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, talend

Has anyone used Talend to connect to the Marketing Cloud SOAP API?

They have Salesforce components, I guess, and Marketo, but I don't see any for Marketing Cloud.

How/can you connect Talend to the Marketing Cloud to use the SOAP API?

Comment: Which talend component are you using?

Comment: The client was trying to use the Salesforce components??? I suggested that those won't work.